# After find missing files, my floor wont cast any shadow

Tags: texturing, materials, light, shadows

i'm working on this project of mine and i've moved the floor's texture files to another folder in order to organise my textures, but i forgot to pack the files into blender. i opened the file and and found the missing files,after that, i realised that my floor object is no longer casting the light/shadows as it should be! i have no idea why :S i have all the files back but i got this prob now

[image: ~Floor Not casting shadows]

Comment: Hello :). Any reason why you're not using the Principled BSDF shader? It's included since Blender 2.79.

Comment: @JachymMichal i am very new to blender nodes, i spent more time learning modelling, meauseremnts inside blender etc... i just followed Blender Guru PBR tutorial, it worked . i just got this prob  after i moved the texts and clicked on "find missing files"

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: @Chris Hello Chris i added the file now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if just loaded your file, changed to rendered view.

result:

[image]

So there is nothing wrong with it. Maybe you checked another file?

Solution: Just download your uploaded file again and it will work! ;)

Comment: you didnt do anything? just downloaded and rendered? because i am still not getting any light/shadows on my floor :( im still trying to figure out

Comment: yes....exactly. i did nothing. did you download the fresh file again? I just used a newer blender version...but this shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: yes i did, but still nothing. i will try to uninstall and install again to se eif it works

Comment: aw finaly i found a solution! but i dont know how to link to your asnwer , it seems its a blender 2.79 bug. I unpack my files and saved, after that i rendered and it worked!